# How do I construct a SELECT statement incorporating Excel cell values?

Tags: excel, postgresql, parameter-passing, excel-2013, powerquery

I am querying an external database with power query through Excel.  What I am wanting to do is populate my where clause  based off of cell values so for example my sql statement would read something like

```
Select *
From employees
where hiredate between Sheet1!A1 and Sheet2!A2
```

I tried the above syntax and it does not work, but I think it illustrates what I am wanting to achieve.

How can I pass parameters from my Excel sheet into my power query syntax?

**EDIT**

I tried following the blog.oraylis.de (not actual link, link is in comments), but I get the below error when I try to execute my statement

> DataSource.Error ODBC:Error[4203] ERROR: column "start_p" does not exist;

I created a table named it parameters added headers & Values, and the full SQL I try to run is this:

```
let
startp_Param = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameter"]}[Content],
startp_Value = startp_Param {0}[Value],
endp_Param = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameter"]}[Content],
endp_Value = endp_Param {1}[Value],
Source = Odbc.Query("dsn=postgresql", "Select * FROM employees where hiredate BETWEEN startp_Value AND endp_Value")
in
Source
```

**EDIT # 2**
I altered my query to read like this

```
"Select * 
FROM employees 
where hiredate BETWEEN " & startp_Value & " AND " & endp_Value
```

However this now presents an error of:

```
"We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Number"
```

Comment: I don't have time to try to do an example, but here's a couple links that should help.  https://blog.oraylis.de/2013/05/using-dynamic-parameter-values-in-power-query-queries/     and    https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95dd4361-cffb-4b12-820a-85c3d041db3e/power-query-query-with-parameter-from-a-cell?forum=powerquery

Comment: one more: http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/

Comment: @StephenLloyd - I tried to follow tutorials - still having issues.  See my edit.

Comment: is the hiredate field an integer or a date?  If it's an integer, try applying a function to the parameter variables that converts to text so that they can be concatenated into the text of the query.  If it's a date field, I believe you will need single quotes to wrap the date values.

Comment: @StephenLloyd - int field.

Answer (score 0):

startp_Value and endp_Value are steps in Power Query, so you have to use & to add it to the string, like this:

`Source = Odbc.Query("dsn=postgresql", "Select * FROM employees where hiredate BETWEEN " & startp_Value & " AND " & endp_Value`

This doesn't handle sanitizating your SQL query, so you may want to do it to startp_Value and endp_Value (for example, by converting to a Date and then back to a Text).

Comment: How would I do the same for text values.  If text value I get an error of "We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Number"

Comment: If startp_Value and endp_Value are numbers, you need to use `Number.ToText(startp_Value)` and `Number.ToText(endp_Value)` instead of `'startp_Value` and `endp_Value`.